# How to control the placement of GameObject in a scene programmatically in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created a code file in Unity and assigned it to an empty `GameObject` I have placed in the scene:

```
var obj = new GameObject("Sample");
obj.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var text = obj.AddComponent<TextMesh>();
text.text = "Hello world";
```

When I run the scene, I can see the text. And that is my problem: I did not specify anywhere in code to add `obj` to the scene, but it gets placed automatically apparently. 
This can be a problem if I want to introduce an object later than instantiation time.

What am I doing wrong? How can this be achieved? What are the patterns/best-practices here?

Comment: Calling new on GameObject will add it to the active scene.  Where else would it place the GameObject?  Also you could deactivate the object immediately and you wouldnt see it in the scene... You can also create a factory method to create objects whenever you specify, or create an object pool...

Comment: @AresCaelum Thanks for the comment. As you can probably see I am a newbie here in Unity. The solution you mentioned about deactivating it immediately seems nice. I am looking for patterns here and best procedures. If you could post an answer with a brief explanation of those it would be awesome

Answer (score 2):

Immediate fix:

Use `obj.SetActive(false)` to temporarily disable the object and then use `obj.SetActive(true)` when you need the object to be active.

Other solutions / best practices:

Create the object you desire in the scene, save it as a prefab (prefabricated object) and then only instantiate it when you need it. Here's a link for further reading into the prefab system. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html

Object pooling is typically used when you will have a bunch of the same objects (like lasers, bullets, etc). Watching this video may be of help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdSmKaJvCoA